# simple gridview with dataset error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In a simple datagridview it gives me error when run (Compilation Error):(Source Error:

Line 11:     
Line 12:
Line 13:         )

mycode

```
public partial class website : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Fillgrid();
}

public void Fillgrid()
{
    Dataset ds = new Dataset();
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; DataBase=first; Integrated Security=true;");
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from attendance", cn);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    cn.Close();
    selectGridView.DataSource = ds;
    selectGridView.DataBind();

}
```

}

Comment: Does this `dataset ds = new dataset();` compiles ? it should be `DataSet`, C# is case sensitive

Comment: I changed it but it gives me another error when run: Line 13:         <asp:GridView ID="selectGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
Line 14:             ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
Line 15:             onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="750px">

Comment: What is the error you get? The second error you mention in your comment is in the aspx file. You have not shared that in your post

Comment: Please provide ASPX page logic for grid

Comment: what is ASPX page logic ?

Comment: Ok, I think your error is not in code behide, your error is in Front End Code, you need to look the gridview's property are right or you can erase this GridView and a put new one

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following code!!

```
  Dataset ds = new Dataset();
  SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; DataBase=first; Integrated        Security=true;");
  cn.Open();
  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from attendance", cn);
  adapter.Fill(ds,"attendance");
  cn.Close();
  selectGridView.DataSource = ds;
  selectGridView.DataBind();
```